# trying to scrape specific data from html tables using beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I was trying to grab time from the below html table. I was able to grab those table in a list but I got alot of data

```
<tr>
<td class="data1">Last update <b class="time">*</b></td>
<td colspan="3">
    <font color="#000000" size="2">10:00 </font><input name="new" type="text" class="myinput"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

I was unable to figure out how to parse the time number

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

source = requests.get('URL')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source.text,'lxml')

table = soup.table
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    for i in td:
        row = [i.text]
        print(row)
```

I am trying to store the time in a string and later use it

Comment: what's the url please? And are you expecting  a single time or a list of times?

Comment: I am expecting single time like a variable X will store it

Comment: I am running the html in localhost so I cant share the link

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to get font elements with color #000000 inside your rows, and then extract time.

Instead of this:

```
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    for i in td:
        row = [i.text]
        print(row)
```

Try this:

```
for tr in table_rows:
    times = [time.text for time in tr.find_all('font', {'color':'#000000'})]
    print(times)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: tried it but the output is coming like this
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
['10:00 ']
[]

Comment: I am trying to get a variable just store that time . I am unable to deal with the list